# Internal Error 500 when sending facebook photo urls >720p to server

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I am trying to send photo urls which are of more than some 700 px . But when i am sending to the data through API . Some photos are uploading but the  other were showing 500 internal error .

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[@"Bearer " stringByAppendingString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"authKey"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSString *urlString=[API Link =%@",fbPic];
   [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{ NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    NSInteger statusCode = operation.response.statusCode;  
}
];
```

and here is the error

```
status code: 500, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
"Content-Length" = 175;
"Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Wed, 29 Jun 2016 12:04:03 GMT";
Expires = "-1";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
"X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
"X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";}
```

Comment: Ask the server developer why it it giving a 500 error, because a 500 error is an internal server error.

Comment: the photo urls which we are sending from android app is successful . but in this code it is showing 500 status code

Comment: Compare the to request, use a proxy server like Charles and look for the differance.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 error indicate that the error comes from the server. You should check with the server developper to get more details

Comment: Maybe you didn't make the exact same request to the server that in the Android app. Check the server's logs if you can

Comment: I have checked and i didnt find any mistake in that , the only thing the photos coming from fb were mostly more than 720px but while we are uploading the url to server , the photos were less than 720px ( like 719*620)